# What is the time complexity of this sorting operation with Python?

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

Let's say I have a list of tuple of tuples like this:

```
L = [(0, 2.0, (2.91, 0.74, 2.20, 1.81, 2.37, 2.51)),
     (1, 2.0, (2.40, 1.03, 0.78, 0.98, 1.30, 2.12)),
     (2, 2.0, (3.80, 2.51, 0.92, 1.84, 0.89, 0.97))]
```

where the the length of `L` is `n`. So in the example above, `n=3`. Every element `i` of `L` is a tuple of tuples of the form `(a, b, c)` where `a` and `b` are numbers but `c` is a tuple of length `k`. So again in the example above, we have `k=6`.

I perform the following python sorting operation:

```
L.sort(key=lambda t: (-t[1], sorted(t[2])))
```

and I need to find what is the worst-case time complexity of this operation?

My thought is: since we have `key=lambda t: (-t[1], sorted(t[2]))` which sorts the tuple `c` of length `k`, then we have `O(k log k)`. Overall, we will have `O(kn log k log n)` but I am not sure how to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

First, the n keys are computed. Each involves sorting k numbers. So that takes O(n • (k log k)) = O(nk • logk) time.

Then the n tuples are sorted, which takes O(n log n) *comparisons*. Since each comparison takes O(k) time, this takes O((n log n) • k) = O(nk • logn) time overall.

Together we have O(nk • (logk + logn)) = O(nk • log(nk)) time. Or simply O(m log m), if we call the total size "m". Interesting...